# Using Legend properties in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, legend

I am trying to input acress right next to values in the Legend; however, I was not able to . See here [image]

Even though I know how to do the Legend Properties. See here

[image: I know how to do this]

Can you point me where can I point to make them move wider ?

Comment: Once you have the information you need in a legend you can right click -> Convert to Graphics.  You'll have to un-group the items, but you have total control over the layout.  Keep in mind that after converting to graphics your legend will no longer auto-update based on changes in layer symbology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to get more space between columns: column gap.
If the item is not already split into 2 columns, you can do this in the Items tab.